# Fill Series VBA Code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a code that will automatically fill sequential numbers depends on the range of data.

here's my code:

```
Dim Lst As Long
Lst = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("A12")
    .Value = "1"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A12").Resize(Lst - 11), Type:=xlFillSeries
End With
```

well it worked fine but I have this output. Last time I already asked on how to clear any duplicates.

here's the output of it when I apply the sequential numbers:

```
No |   Col 2   | Col 1
  1|  Person 1 | 1. Question 1
  2|           | 2. Question 2
  3|           | 3. Question 3
    -------------------------
  4|  Person 2 | 1. Question 1
  5|           | 2. Question 2
  6|           | 3. Question 3
    -------------------------
  7| Person 3  | 1. Question 1
  8|           | 2. Question 2
  9|           | 3. Question 3
```

I want to have it like this:

```
No |   Col 2   | Col 1
  1|  Person 1 | 1. Question 1
   |           | 2. Question 2
   |           | 3. Question 3
    -------------------------
  2|  Person 2 | 1. Question 1
   |           | 2. Question 2
   |           | 3. Question 3
    -------------------------
  3| Person 3  | 1. Question 1
   |           | 2. Question 2
   |           | 3. Question 3
```

but I don't know how? or what will I add to the code.
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by finding out which row in Column B has a Person then use that row to insert the incremented value into Column A's respective row.

To learn more have a look through the below code reading the comments to give you tips on what the code is doing.

```
Sub OrderColumn()
    Dim cellsInRange As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Range("B12:B" & LastRow(2)) 'Use LastRow(column) function to find the last row with a value in "column".
    i = 0 'This is our value that increments.

    For Each cellsInRange In selectedRange.Cells
        If Range("B" & (cellsInRange.Row)).Value = "" Then
            'Do nothing.
        Else
            i = i + 1 'Increment i by 1.
            Range("A" & (cellsInRange.Row)).Value = i 'Add i as the new cell value.
        End If
    Next cellsInRange

End Sub
Function LastRow(column As Long)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```